# Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch when shelling out to a command that invokes Ruby

Tags: shell, rake, bundler, runtime-error, heroku-toolbelt

A Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch error is emitted (from Bundler-managed code) when shelling out to a command which itself uses another version of Ruby.

This happens when a Ruby version is specified in Gemfile, on some systems, for some shell commands.

One class of examples for this are Rake tasks shelling out to Heroku toolbelt commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code, wrap `Bundler.with_clean_env{}` around the command shelled-out to.

More information on this is available in a Bundler [issue](https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/2355).